# Failed to connect to mongodb in Bluemix, failed to find certificate path

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, ibm-cloud, compose-db

I am unable to connect to my Compose MongoDB service from my deployed bluemix app.  It seems that it cannot find the necessary certificate.  I had expected that it would pick that up directly from environment variable VCAP_SERVICES.

I can run this fine from my local test environment because I imported the key into the appropriate keystore in Java.

If I look at their node.js sample on bluemix they are actually passing the certificate during the connect.  However, I cannot find this anywhere on the Java API.

I believe that I either need to add this cert to the VM on bluemix (seems unlikely) or I need to pass it via the Java driver when I cannot (can't see how).

Thoughts?

For the record, this is the exception I get:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches 
ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of 
cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=bluemix-sandbox-dal-9-portal.7.dblayer.com:26123, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}}, {address=bluemix-sandbox-dal-9-portal.6.dblayer.com:26123, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}, caused by {sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target}}]
com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:377)
com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:104)
com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:402)
com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:510)
com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)
com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl$FindOperationIterable.first(FindIterableImpl.java:216)
com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:156)
com.ibm.smarts.experiment.UserMgr.getUserDetails(UserMgr.java:146)
com.ibm.smarts.experiment.UserMgr.authenticateUser(UserMgr.java:123)
com.ibm.smarts.experiment.servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:31)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: The Liberty for Java buildpack should be generating a server.xml for you with a MongoDB datasource and keystore. Can you connect that way instead of parsing VCAP_SERVICES and initializing the Java client yourself?

Comment: I'm using tomcat rather than liberty. Is there a similar server.xml file for that?

Comment: I can connect from my local machine by parsing the VCAP I get firm bluemix. I added it to the local Java keystone.

Comment: I've added a few more options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813280/how-to-upload-ssl-certificate-to-bluemix

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options documented [here](https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/223454928-How-to-tell-application-containers-running-Java-apps-to-trust-self-signed-certs-or-a-private-internal-CA).  For example:

Import the cert to Java truststore file, pack the file into Java application and specify its path via JAVA_OPTS environment variable; the truststore file can be placed under resource directory. This can be used for single applications:

By using the 'cf set-env' command:

```
cf set-env <app> JAVA_OPTS '-Djavax.net.ssl.TrustStore=classpath:resources/config/truststore'
```

By using manifest.yml:

```
---
applications:
- name: java-app
  ...
  env:
    JAVA_OPTS: '-Djavax.net.ssl.TrustStore=classpath:resources/config/truststore'
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I will try it and report back.

Comment: I cannot seem to get this to work and I'm not sure how to debug it actually.  
The first question is whether it is TrustStore or trustStore. I tried both.  
This is what I have in the manifest:  
`applications:
- path: target/RecommenderExperiment.war
  ....
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  env:
    JAVA_OPTS: '-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=classpath:/resources/cacert -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit'`
Now what I have in the war file structure is this:
  `target\WEB-INF\classes\cacerts`
I also tried without 'resources' in the path.
How can I figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Can you try to create a minimal example so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Well, actually it looks like if I switch from using Tomcat to Liberty this problem goes away.  I wish I could understand how to get tomcat to work but the main thing right now is to get it running.