# How to add SSL certificate to Bluemix java cloud foundry application?

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, ibm-cloud

I am developing microservices using Spring Boot, Java JDK 1.8, MongoDB driver for Java, and MongoDB. I have created MongoDB instance on Bluemix and I am connecting to this instance from Java microservices.

The MongoDB instance on Bluemix is SSL enabled and it provides the SSL certificate. For local development, I have Base64 decoded this certificate and I have imported this SSL certificate to the my local java keystore. So locally I am able to connect to the MongoDB instance on Bluemix without any issues.

When I am deploying my spring boot microservices as jar file to Bluemix using cf CLI, the microservices are unable to connect to the MongoDB on Bluemix because I haven't uploaded the SSL certificate which was provided by MongoDB.

Can someone please let me know the steps needed to upload the SSL certificate to Bluemix so my microservices can connect to the MongoDB instance?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1a**

If you have a single certificate, you can use the [spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen) which adds the certificate to the system truststore inside the buildpack:

First you need this in your pom.xml (or alternative):

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com </url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
       <releases>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orange.clara.cloud.boot.ssl-truststore-gen</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.21</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are creating a cloud foundry app, next declare the certificate in your manifest.yml:

```
env:
    TRUSTED_CA_CERTIFICATE: |-
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        changeme
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When you `cf push` your application, the certificate will get added to the truststore.

If you aren't creating a cloud foundry app, set the enivonment variable `TRUSTED_CA_CERTIFICATE` with the value of your certificate, e.g.

```
$ export TRUSTED_CA_CERTIFICATE=<TRUSTED_CA_CERTIFICATE_VALUE>
```

**Option 1b**

The spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen library [does not support](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen/commit/3d6cf29ad8bad0cd5d2df86865b60dfc75d996d8) loading multiple certificates from the TRUSTED_CA_CERTIFICATE environment variable.  If you have multiple certificates, you can try directly calling the ssl-truststore-gen api, e.g. from a static block in one of your classes:

```
package helloworld;

import com.orange.clara.cloud.boot.ssl.CertificateFactory;
import com.orange.clara.cloud.boot.ssl.DefaultTrustStoreAppender;
import com.orange.clara.cloud.boot.ssl.TrustStoreInfo;

public class CertLoader {

    public static final String SSL_TRUST_STORE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY = "javax.net.ssl.trustStore";
    public static final String SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD_SYSTEM_PROPERTY = "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword";

    static {
        String[] certs = {
            System.getenv("CERTIFICATE_1"),
            System.getenv("CERTIFICATE_2")
        };

        for (String cert : certs) {
            DefaultTrustStoreAppender trustStoreAppender = new DefaultTrustStoreAppender();
            TrustStoreInfo trustStoreInfo = trustStoreAppender.append(CertificateFactory.newInstance(cert));
            System.setProperty(SSL_TRUST_STORE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, trustStoreInfo.getTrustStorefFile().getAbsolutePath());
            System.setProperty(SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, trustStoreInfo.getPassword());
        }
    }
}
```

You would then need something like the following in your manifest.yml:

```
env:
    CERTIFICATE_1: |-
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        changeme
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----

    CERTIFICATE_2: |-
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        changeme
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Option 1c**

Add the following to your pom.xml to automatically load the ssl certificates when your application starts up using https://github.com/snowch/spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen:

```
<repository>
   <id>jitpack.io</id>
   <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.snowch</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen</artifactId>
   <version>master</version>
</dependency>
```

or to your Gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

compile 'com.github.snowch:spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen:master'
```

**Option 2**

If you are creating a cloud foundry app and using the liberty buildpack see this question and the accepted answer for adding a ssl certificate: [Add certificate to truststore to enable SSL communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180717/add-certificate-to-truststore-to-enable-ssl-communication/44621986#44621986)

**Option 3**

If you have access to the socket, e.g. You are instantiating a `MongoClient()` instance yourself rather than letting a library such as spring cloud connectors handle this for you, you could try https://www.compose.com/articles/easier-java-connections-to-mongodb-at-compose-2/

Comment: thanks for your response. I need to add multiple SSL certificates to manifest.yml file as I have multiple MongoDB instances on Bluemix to connect to. Can you please let me know how to add TRUSTED_CA_CERTIFICATE for multiple SSL certificates in manifest.yml file?

Comment: I've updated option 1 with more information.  Please let me know how you get on.

Comment: Chris, can you please let me know how can we add multiple SSL certifcates in manifest.yml file or is there any limitation with this approach?

Comment: The spring-boot-ssl-truststore-gen does not support this.  I've updated the answer to give you a possible workaround.

Comment: Chris, tried option 1b mentioned above and got the following ex: "App/0 java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN is not trusted; internal cause is:App/0 java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error. App/0Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath". After this I tried Option 2 mentioned below using Server.xml file and I also converted jar to war file and got the same exception.

Comment: Can you put some println's in the CertLoader class to verify that the methods are getting run to add the certificates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148081/discussion-between-chris-snow-and-jumping-jack).

Comment: Chris, can you please share a sample server.xml file with SSL details?

Comment: See here for a quick hack example https://github.com/snowch/hello-spring-cloud/tree/multiple_ssl/